# How to access to a special html tag

Tags: jquery, html, tags

I have a li like bellow

```
<li id="theOne">     
  <label class="clearer">
    <strong>One day</strong>  
    <small>Price: 50</small>
    <strong>Two days</strong>  
    <small>Price: 90</small>
  </label>
</li>
```

I used these jQuery functions to copy and paste it where I want :

```
$("li#theOne .clearer strong").after().appendTo(".passTitle");
```

I would like to know how to copy the first strong tag and not the second, without adding css class ?

Comment: `$("li#theOne .clearer strong").first().after().appendTo(".passTitle")`

Comment: You can use `first()` to select the first element found in a selector. Also, your usage of `after()` is redundant and can be removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `.eq()` in jquery

```
$("li#theOne .clearer strong:eq(0)").after().appendTo(".passTitle");
```

or

```
$("li#theOne .clearer strong)").eq(0).after().appendTo(".passTitle");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `first`

```
$("li#theOne .clearer strong").first().appendTo(".passTitle");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
$("li#theOne .clearer strong:first").after().appendTo(".passTitle");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$("li#theOne .clearer strong").first().after().appendTo(".passTitle")
```